# rpmbuild install dependency

Tags: rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I'm new to rpmbuild + spec files and I tried the following [tutorial](https://blog.packagecloud.io/rpm/rpmbuild/packaging/2015/06/29/building-rpm-packages-with-rpmbuild/) to build the "hello world" example.

Manage to get it working, but I wanted to learn how dependencies/requires works. Therefore, I tried to duplicate another "hello world 2" example and link it as a dependency to the first in the spec file below.

However I keep getting the error below. Is there a way that yum install will pick up the helloworld1 and install automatically when i yum install helloworld2 ?

Any example for me learn from?

**SPEC FILE**

```
Name:           helloworld2
Version:        2.0
Release:        1%{?dist}
Summary:        A hello world program

License:        GPLv3+
URL:            https://blog.packagecloud.io
Source0:        helloworld2-2.0.tar.gz

#BuildRequires: helloworld1
Requires(preun):  helloworld1
#PreReq: testYW

%description
A helloworld program from the packagecloud.io blog!

%prep
%setup

%build
make PREFIX=/usr %{?_smp_mflags}

%install
make PREFIX=/usr DESTDIR=%{?buildroot} install
echo %{?buildroot}

%clean
rm -rf %{buildroot}

%files
%{_bindir}/helloworld2
```

**ERORR**

COMMAND >> yum install RPMS/x86_64/helloworld2-2.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm

```
Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos, security, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Setting up Install Process
Examining RPMS/x86_64/helloworld2-2.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm: helloworld2-2.0-1.el6.x86_64
Marking RPMS/x86_64/helloworld2-2.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package helloworld2.x86_64 0:2.0-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: helloworld1 for package: helloworld2-2.0-1.el6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: helloworld2-2.0-1.el6.x86_64 (/helloworld2-2.0-1.el6.x86_64)
           Requires: helloworld1
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
```

Answer (score 2):

since helloworld2 requires helloworld1; you should either install helloworld1 first; either install both together. Since helloworld2 depends on helloworld1; you cannot install him without installing helloworld1 first (or at the same time).

Answer (score 0):

okay ! i got the answer !

i can either do a yum install *.rpm , which it will do its own dependency

else putting all the new rpm file into the repository and it will pick it up :)